# what is the Same method as sql data reader in delphi?

Tags: sql, delphi, sqldatareader

The closes way to retrieved data ?

```
SQLCmd.CommandText = "SELECT NAMA,SEKSYEN FROM STUDENT_INFORMATION WHERE MATRIC='" & TextBox1.Text & "'"

rd = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader

If rd.HasRows Then
   rd.Read()

   TextBox2.Text = rd.Item("NAMA").ToString
   TextBox3.Text = rd.Item("SEKSYEN").ToString

   rd.Close()

Else
   TextBox2.Text = ""
   TextBox3.Text = ""
   MessageBox.Show("No Data!")

End If
```

I have some piece of it. But don't know if there's any same method like `SqlDataReader` in Delphi 7

```
with ADOQuery1 do
  begin
    SQL.Clear;
    SQL.Add('Select *');
    SQL.Add('from REPORT');
    SQL.Add('where CARD_ID = "' + card1.Text + '"');

    if  then
    begin
   Edit1.Text = rd.Item("SEKSYEN").AsString ;// wrong code trying to convert from above . not complete
   ComboBox1.Text = rd.Item("SEKSYEN").AsString;// wrong code trying to convert from above . not complete
   ComboBox2.Text = rd.Item("SEKSYEN").AsString ;// wrong code trying to convert from above . not complete
   Edit2.Text = rd.Item("SEKSYEN").AsString  ; // wrong code trying to convert from above . not complete
   end;
```

Could you help me ? I'm stuck

Comment: You can access field by its name with `ADOQuery1.FieldByName('SEKSYEN').AsString` after you `Open` the dataset. You'll be standing on the first record of the dataset that time. To get to the next record, use the `ADOQuery.Next` method.

Comment: i mean do you know any substitutions in hasrow/read in delphi?

Comment: Use `query.First` to move to the first record, then check for `not query.EOF` to make sure there is actually at least one record.

Comment: Rows are read automatically while you are iterating the dataset, so there is no `Read` method alternative.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation of [`TDataSet`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TDataSet) (-> Methods has all you need) and expect different behaviour. But the method-names are talking to you (`IsEmpty` instead of `HasRows`)

Comment: Alternatively, query `RecordCount`.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent `ExecuteReader` is `Open`. `HasRows` is `IsEmpty`, and the way to read individual columns from a row is using the `Fields` collection via `FieldByName`:

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('Select *');
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('from REPORT');
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('where CARD_ID = "' + card1.Text + '"');
ADOQuery1.Open;

if not ADOQuery1.IsEmpty then
begin
  Edit1.Text = ADOQuery1.FieldByName('SEKSYEN').AsString ;
  ComboBox1.Text = ADOQuery1.FieldByName('SEKSYEN').AsString;
  ComboBox2.Text = ADOQuery1.FieldByName('SEKSYEN').AsString ;
  Edit2.Text = ADOQuery1.FieldByName('SEKSYEN').AsString; 
end;
```